# deploy capistrano ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

what it means, when i deploy my project i have error :

```
 ** transaction: commit
* 2014-01-10 15:52:54 executing `deploy:bundle'
  * executing "cd /var/www/current; bundle install"
    servers: ["10.3.27.72"]
    [10.3.27.72] executing command
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] /home/shibanov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 0 total gem(s) (
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] Gem::LoadError)
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] from /home/shibanov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] from /home/shibanov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] from /home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@sprut/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] from /home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@sprut/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 ** [out :: 10.3.27.72] from /home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@sprut/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    command finished in 41ms
failed: "env PATH=/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@sprut/bin:/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@sprut/bin:/home/shibanov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/home/shibanov/.rvm/bin:$PATH RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.0.0-p195 GEM_HOME=/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/uby-2.0.0-p195@sprut GEM_PATH=/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/uby-2.0.0-p195@sprut:/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/uby-2.0.0-p195@sprut BUNDLE_PATH=/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/uby-2.0.0-p195@sprut sh -c 'cd /var/www/current; bundle install'" on 10.3.27.72
```

it error happen when i migrate project from ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `GEM_HOME` accordingly:

```
$ export GEM_HOME='/home/shibanov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195'
```